# How to replace a value in Bracket with negative value in ssis

Tags: sql, ssis

I have imported data into a database from an excel file and some of the columns contain values are like `(392.03)`, `(2.25)`, `(65.00)`. Actually these values should be -ve values can you guys help me to convert these into `-392.03`,`-2.25`,`-65.00`

Answer (score 0):

```
DECLARE @NumValue DEC (9,3) = 0
DECLARE @StrValue varchar(15) = '(392.03)'
IF LEFT(@StrValue,1)='(' and RIGHT(@StrValue,1)=')'
BEGIN
    SET @StrValue = SUBSTRING(@StrValue,2,LEN(@StrValue)-2)
    SET @NumValue = convert(DEC (9,3), @StrValue) 
END

SELECT @NumValue
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this in the derived column

```
SUBSTRING([Paid Amount],1,1) == "(" ? REPLACE(REPLACE([Paid Amount],"(","-"),")","") : [Paid Amount]
```

Then use a Data conversion step to convert the value yo Float DT_R4